# Unable to find or create trash directory for /usb/passport/

Tags: raspbian, fstab

I'm trying to delete a folder from an external USB drive I have mounted. The error I receive is "Season 2: Unable to find or create trash directory for /usb/passport/Season 2"

I added a line for the drive in /etc/fstab, so I'm thinking I maybe didn't modify it correctly. The contents of fstab are currently:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

UUID=22F8F236F8F207B5 /usb/passport ntfs defaults,auto,rw,nofail 0 1
```

Did I do something incorrectly when mounting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default NTFS driver is RO.
There is a *ntfs-3g  read/write NTFS driver for FUSE* in the repository.

There may also be permission issues. You may need to change uid/gid to 1000 for user pi.
I haven't used NTFS for years, but used to mount with:-
`/mnt/SeagateNTFS     ntfs    rw,noauto,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8`

Comment: Is it as simple as changing the format in /etc/fstab, and do I need to unmount and remount as the correct type?

Comment: You need to install ntfs-3g with `sudo spt install ntfs-3g`

Comment: That did it! I had it installed already, but I just changed it to ntfs-3g instead of ntfs in /etc/fstab and rebooted. Problem solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ntfs-3g is a built in package in RaspiOS32. So there's no need to "install it". @Milliways